# Rewrite Rule not catching strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This rewrite rule works fine with number variables, but do not work with strings

```
RewriteRule ^\d+$ user.php?user=$0 [L,QSA]
```

who to make this rule accepts for example:

www.mydomain.com/user/**AndreMendes**

right now only accepts if is **user/12334** or any number.

How to make it accepts strings and numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

To match alphanumbric characters in URI You need the following regex pattern.

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]
```

Comment: there is a problem. it is catching everything .  Need to avoid catching .php or .html extensions